# Footnoterule not working with mathdesign font

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, mathdesign

So I've been using pdfTeX, article *documentclass*.

This is my footnote (apparently, it should stretch to the whole page in width):

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hrule width \textwidth\vspace*{0.3cm}}
```

It does render itself just fine. But then, when I change the font to a *mathdesign* one, this footnote formatting is lost to me, reverting to the default footnote appearance.

This is all it takes to lose my footnote formatting:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
```

So, how does one get their footnote formatting back, even with mathdesign font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` *after* the `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hrule width \textwidth\vspace*{0.3cm}}
\begin{document}
x\footnote{pdq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the subdirectories of the `mathdesign` package (which are invoked by the package), for example, in `mdbch.sty`, you will find the footnote rule explicitly redefined

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@height \rulethickness \@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
```

Thus, any attempt by the user to override this must be specified *after* the `mathdesign` package is loaded.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks, Steve! Not being a TeX meister like you, I had no idea that there is a file like mdbch.sty out there.

Comment: @FatBastard The subdirectories correspond to different font families.  Looking in `\mathdesign.sty`, subdirectory `mdput` is for utopia font, `mdugm` is for garamond, `mdbch` is for charter, `mdpus` is for commercial version of utopia, `mdpgd` for commercial garamond, and `mdici` for commercial charter font.